# In Symfony2 no input file specified

Tags: php, ubuntu, symfony

I installed Symfony2 on localhost. It works, but, when I deploy the application on a remote server, I see following error:

> No input file specified.

What could be causing this ?

Notes:

1. I changed the `parameters.ini` file based on `databasename` and `password`.
2. OS is Ubuntu

Comment: Please could you provide the exact error you see (in the console when you make app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug and in the browser after clearing the cache in the console)

Comment: Hi, this is my online url http://projectsdisplay.com/Dotslinker/web/app.php/projectdetails but it shows "No input file specified" but in localhost, url is localhost/padma/Dotslinker/web/app.php/logindetails/ it shows result.

Comment: When i modified in localhost in twig file and saved then refresh page also no changes.So i CLEAR THE CACHE FILE AS php app/console cache:clear --env=prod it display result.but each time i want to clear cache in localhost.    Whether i need to change any other file like app.php,app_dev.php for online or i want to change url.                        Thanks,                                                                Padma

Comment: In localhost you have to access to your project via `app_dev.php` and you do not need any cache clear. In production you have to access to your project via `app.php` and you need to clear the cache anytime a change is made by running `php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug`. Notice: by using the default .htaccess of your Symfony2 project, in production every URL without `app.php` uses `app.php` so you don't have to use any special URL to access your project in production.

Comment: In localhost also  .htaccess file not created .i tried app_dev.php not working but app.php is getting result in localhost.but in online shall i want to change any file. in ubuntu                                       Thanks

Comment: Hi, this is my online url projectsdisplay.com/Dotslinker/web/app.php/projectdetails but it shows "No input file specified" but in localhost, url is localhost/padma/Dotslinker/web/app.php/logindetails/ it shows result.

Comment: what are the files i need to change from localhost to online,simple in symfony2 ubuntu.also say sample url like.                                    Thanks

Comment: You have to access to your localhost project with this url : localhost/padma/Dotslinker/web/**app_dev.php**/logindetails/
You have to access to your online project with this url :  projectsdisplay.com/Dotslinker/web/projectdetails (after having cleared the cache and with the correct .htaccess)

Comment: http://localhost/padma/Dotslinker/web/app_dev.php/logindetails/new  the RuntimeException: You need to enable either the SQLite3 or PDO_SQLite extension for the profiler to run properly.but in http://localhost/padma/Dotslinker/web/app.php/logindetails/new no exception.sure i need to go with app_dev.php                          Thanks

Comment: In my symfony2 project, .htaccess and config.php not created what i should change.                                                                Thanks

Comment: Your Symfony2 installation seems to no be good. Please refer to the official documentation in order to have a proper installation. There are too many problems with your installation and I cannot provide you a concise response. You definitely have to re-install your Symfony2.

Comment: Oh ok thank you very much, i will reinstall can u say video url to install symfony2 ubuntu